# Passing complex data directly between Fragments?What's wrong with the code?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to pass data between 2 fragments.the data i am passing is an object of a class SongDetails.Here is the Code for  the fragment which is passing the data

```
ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo =new........;
if (Songinfo.size()>0)//Songinfo is an object of the class SongDetails..

        {
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

         bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Fragdata",Songinfo);
         dv.setArguments(bundle);

        }
```

code for receiving the data

```
Bundle bundle=this.getArguments(); 
    final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo =bundle.getParcelableArrayList("Fragdata");
```

when i run this it the app crashes...what am i be  doing wrong??

the code for the SongDetails

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class SongDetails implements Parcelable {
    Bitmap icon;
    String song;
    String Artist;
    String Album;
    String Path;
    int time;
    int icLauncher;

    public SongDetails() {
    }

    public SongDetails(Parcel in) {
        String[] data = new String[4];
        in.readStringArray(data);
        this.Path = data[0];
        this.song= data[1];
        this.Album= data[2];
        this.Artist = data[3];
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return Artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String Artist) {
        this.Artist = Artist;
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.icon = bitmap;
    }

    public String getPath2() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath2(String Path) {
        this.Path = Path;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return Album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String Album) {
        this.Album = Album;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icLauncher) {
        this.icLauncher = icLauncher;
    }










    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.Path,this.song,this.Album,this.Artist });

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public SongDetails createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SongDetails(in);
        }

        public SongDetails[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SongDetails[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: please paste the logcat. What error are you getting?

Comment: And what the SongInfo is? Paste the code of it.

Comment: Songinfo is an object of the class songdetails

Comment: You can always pass messages via a global static field(s).

Comment: @SargeBorsch for e.g?

Comment: u mean if i declare Songinfo static and make it global,will it accessible in another fragment?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Of course. All public static fields and methods (of public classes) are accessible from everywhere at any time.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I would suggest to use naming conventions, your code is unclear.

Comment: @RiteshGune i can't...my emulator doesn't work properly,so i have to use my phone to test the apps

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava you can connect your phone to your PC and can get the logcat, not a big deal.

Comment: @RiteshGune well its difficult to explain .....is there any problem with the code??

(the phone i use isn't mine,so i don't have access to it all the time and right now i am in a class(college ) so i don't have access to my code as well)

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, I would like to have a look at it, but ask that as another question in separate thread.

Comment: If you are not confortable with OOP programation you can always use the Application var which is accessible averywhere in the application and singleton

Comment: for e.g?................

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava what is the error in logcat exactly?

Comment: i am using a phone,and that too isn't mine so i don't have it right now,and i don't know how i can setup the phone to show the logcat

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava you should really prepare a development environment for you. Maybe you can run the app in emulator and see stack trace there. Otherwise you can only guess what is wrong...

Comment: @beworker yeah i have been advised that alot....there are many problems i face..my emulator won't connect to the internet also,its sd card's permission won't change,i have tried many things but they were of no use...hey can you help me with one thing.....can you please upload the image of your sdcard(emulator) with read/write permission?i can try that if it works or not...

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava The image is big, I don't think I know where to upload it. I would rather suggest you to update android SDK and eclipse plugins to the latest version and to recreate emulator. Make sure you choose SD Card size and set size to at least 100 MB. Working development environment is essential part of success of any project.

Comment: i have tried literally everything available on internet...even the solution you have provided...:(..whats the size of your sdcard by the way?

Comment: you can mail your sdcard ....my email id is rixxx22@yahoo.com
and can you please push 4-5 songs in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass data directly between 2 fragments. Instead you have to pass data from your fragment 1 to your activity through an interface that you must have previously created.

Then, inside the implemented method in your activity, you should retrieve the object reference to fragment 2 and call a public method that you created and do the job.

There is a good tutorial in Android official documentation:

[Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Comment: no you are wrong...there is a way.....thats why i have mentioned in the question "directly".............its not recommended though...

Answer (score 0):

To path any data from anywhere to anywhere else in your app use EventBus library. You can also do it by implementing observer design pattern but using library is far more easier since it also handles thread switching for you (just in case you need it)
here is the link
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus